# Add existing instances to a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to add existing instances in the GCP to a kubernetes cluster?

I can see the inputs while creating the cluster in graphically mode is :

Cluster Name,
Location,
Zone,
Cluster Version,
Machine type,
Size.

In command mode:

```
gcloud container clusters create cluster-name --num-nodes=4
```

I'm having 10 running instances.

I need to create the kubernetes cluster with the already existing running instances

Answer (score 1):

On your instance run the following

```
kubelet --api_servers=http://<API_SERVER_IP>:8080 --v=2 --enable_server --allow-privileged
kube-proxy --master=http://<API_SERVER_IP>:8080 --v=2
```

This will connect your slave node to your existing cluster. Its actually surprisingly simple